# SQL - Multiple duplicates in some columns, 1 column has to be unique

Tags: sql, sqlite, duplicates, unique

I'm quite novice with SQL and would really appreciate some help on this one for a project I'm working on. I'm using SQLite, not sure if that makes a difference!

I need to write a query that outputs a row if 3 columns are the same but 1 column is different.

Column 2, 3, and 4 combined must have a duplicate in another row,

but

Column 1, 2, 3, and 4 combined must not have any duplicates in any other rows.

**An example database:**

```
ROW 1 : 12345 | Test1 | Something1 | And1  (I don't want this, it's a full row duplicate with row 2)

ROW 2 : 12345 | Test1 | Something1 | And1  (I don't want this, it's a full row duplicate with row 1)

ROW 3 : 12344 | Test1 | Something1 | And3  (I don't want this, it's not a full row duplicate but col 2, 3 and 4 combined doesn't exist anywhere else in the table)

ROW 4 : 12222 | Test2 | Something1 | And2  (I want this! It's not a full row duplicate and columns 2, 3 and 4 combined exists in row 9) 

ROW 5 : 12222 | Test3 | Something1 | And3

ROW 6 : 12222 | Test3 | Something1 | And3

ROW 7 : 12224 | Test3 | Something1 | And3

ROW 8 : 12222 | Test3 | Something2 | And3

ROW 9 : 12000 | Test2 | Something1 | And2
```

**The output I'd want for this is:**

```
12222 | Test2 | Something1 | And2

12224 | Test3 | Something1 | And3

12000 | Test2 | Something1 | And2
```

I hope this makes sense to someone. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Your expected output doesn't really make sense.  There is no `12222 | Test2 | Something1 | And2` record in the input table.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for your comment I'll adjust it.

Comment: @Aldeguer I've tried too much to mention everything

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen now I've changed it.. is that the output you were imagining I should have put?

Comment: I still don't understand your output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The first 2 rows aren't output because they're duplicate rows, the third row isn't output because the last 3 columns (Test1 | Something1 | And3) don't appear in any other rows, the 4th row is output because the last 3 columns also appears in the last row (Test2 | Something1 | And2) but the first column (12222 and 12000) aren't the same - so the rows aren't identical, but the last 3 columns have a match

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'll try changing my question to see if it makes more sense

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think it's a lot clearer now... can you please help me?!

Comment: @ChrisLaidler `12224` should still **not** be appearing in the result set.  I added a demo to my answer to show this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen 12224 meets all of my criteria though. Doesn’t that mean your results and query must be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.col2 = t.col2 and t2.col3 = t.col3 and t2.col4 = t.col4 and
                    t2.col1 <> t.col1
             );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it's not entirely what I wanted. Could be my fault, as I put the wrong output... doesn't help! With this query, I'm still getting duplicates across entire rows.

Answer (score 0):

We can join to a subquery which identifies duplicate groups, and restrict using it:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT col2, col3, col4
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY col2, col3, col4
    HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(DISTINCT col1) AND COUNT(*) > 1
) t2
    ON t1.col2 = t2.col2 AND t1.col3 = t2.col3 AND t1.col4 = t2.col4;
```

### Demo

Comment: Your logic makes no sense to me, and I won't change my answer, because AFAIK I have implemented the logic your described in your question.  If you expect _different_ results, then edit your question and **clearly** tell us what the logic is.  The point here is not to make everyone dance until someone guesses a "correct" query, but rather to ask a correct question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 
col1,
col2,
col3,
col4
from (
SELECT 
*,
LEAD(valid, 1, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY col2, col3, col4 ORDER BY col1) as valid_next,
LEAD(invalid, 1, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY col2, col3, col4 ORDER BY col1) as invalid_next
FROM (
SELECT
*,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col2, col3, col4 ORDER BY col1) AS valid,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3, col4 ORDER BY col1) AS invalid
FROM tb1
) x ) y
where valid <> valid_next and invalid = invalid_next
ORDER BY col1;
```

The logic here is to create two columns (`valid` and `invalid`) to count the occurrence of 1) 3 duplicated columns, and 2) 4 duplicated columns. Then use `lag` to track the change. If there is a change then we know there are duplicates, otherwise the row would be unique to the columns partitioned.

Output table:

```
+--------+--------+-------------+------+
| col1   | col2   |    col3     | col4 |
+--------+--------+-------------+------+
| 12000  | Test2  | Something1  | And2 |
| 12222  | Test2  | Something1  | And2 |
| 12224  | Test3  | Something1  | And3 |
+--------+--------+-------------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks so much Larry, this looks more like what I'm after. I'm going to try it out later and get back to you to let you know

Comment: This assumes that the OP's version of SQLite supports `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: I’m using SQLite 3.15

Comment: Not sure if I’m doing something wrong but I cant get this to work. Is tb1 supposed to be my table name? I’m not sure where I’m supposed to say what table I’m using?

Comment: Yes, tb1 is the table name. What's the error message? If your sqlite does not support row_number then try Tim's query, otherwise this query should work.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me Larry. I think the problem might be that I also have an id column. I’m using nodejs and some other modules, so I’m not sure my error message will help here

Comment: Larry, I’ve noticed that you and Tim have different results, between you.. you’re almost there. Just not quite there

Comment: Chris, I have updated my query and output which should be what you are looking for. So the basic idea is using `lag` to identify whether there is a change on `valid` and `invalid`, so that we can tell whether a duplication exist in column 2-4 (valid) and column 1-4 (invalid)

Comment: Thanks Larry, I've since realised that I don't actually have a version of SQLite that supports ROW_NUMBER